# GraphQL Dynamic Query SQL Injection

Tags: facebook-graph-api, graphql, sql-injection, graphql-js, graphql-java

Question about GraphQL and its vulnerability to SQL injections. Say I have some dynamic search being performed, where a user enters text into a field, and I use this as a parameter to a graphQL search.

So, I end up with something like this:

```
{
   data {
     location: user_input
  }
}
```

where user_input is a variable specified by the user.

Now, say a user were to try and enter some malevolent code here, to wipe the database or something along those lines (i.e. a 1=1 attack). Would this work here? Does GraphQL simply translate the queries into SQL and thus could this be dangerous? Or will GraphQL prevent such things from happening?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

GraphQL is a query language. From the [spec](http://spec.graphql.org/draft/#sec-Overview):

> GraphQL is a query language designed to build client applications by providing an intuitive and flexible syntax and system for describing their data requirements and interactions... GraphQL is not a programming language capable of arbitrary computation, but is instead a language used to query application servers that have capabilities defined in this specification. GraphQL does not mandate a particular programming language or storage system for application servers that implement it.

GraphQL is agnostic about the underlying data layer. It can be used with a SQL database, but it could also be used with a NoSQL database, an in-memory key-value store, a file system, etc.

Whether a particular GraphQL service is vulnerable to SQL injection ultimately depends on how that service was implemented. The fact that it's a GraphQL service doesn't really factor into it.